# Which Destiny-like FPS game is this picture from?

Tags: pc, game-identification

I have only this picture of the game:
[image: Picture]

We thought it's the Destiny game, but GUIs are different.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a free to play game Dust 514 made by CCP Games. This game is only for Playstation 3 and it is heavily tied with Eve Online universe which is sci-fi mmo game.

Answer (score 3):

Going by this image it seems that the HUD elements are quite similar. The one provided by the OP seems to have a little skew to it as if it were to be projected onto a curved screen. The armour of the players seem to be similar to Dust 514 as well.

[image: Reference image]